# ¿Como puedo cambiar el orden de los valores de una lista en un json en python?

Tags: python, json

> Este es mi codigo, estoy trabajando con python y para ver el formato json, estoy usando postman

```
def listarID(self, id):
        con = db().open
        cursor = con.cursor()

        sql = """ 
                SELECT proy.id, proy.nombre, proy.fechaIni, proy.fechaFin, proy.presupuesto, proy.estado FROM proyecto_empleado pro 
                INNER JOIN empleado empl ON pro.idEmp=empl.id INNER JOIN proyecto proy ON pro.idPro=proy.id
                WHERE empl.id=%s
                """
        cursor.execute(sql, [id])
        datos=cursor.fetchall()
        cursor.close()

        con.close()
        
        if datos:
            return json.dumps({'status': True, 'data': datos, 'message': 'Proyectos asociados a un empleado'}, cls=CustomJsonEncoder, sort_keys=False)
        else:
            return json.dumps({'status': False, 'data': [], 'message': 'Sin registros'})
```

> se muestra asi, la data se muestra alfabeticamente:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "estado": "Activo",
            "fechaFin": "2023-11-12",
            "fechaIni": "2023-06-01",
            "id": 1,
            "nombre": "Proyecto A",
            "presupuesto": 50000
        },
        {
            "estado": "Activo",
            "fechaFin": "2023-11-04",
            "fechaIni": "2023-01-01",
            "id": 2,
            "nombre": "Proyecto B",
            "presupuesto": 20000
        },
        {
            "estado": "Activo",
            "fechaFin": "2023-11-03",
            "fechaIni": "2023-02-03",
            "id": 3,
            "nombre": "Proyecto C",
            "presupuesto": 34000
        }
    ],
    "message": "Proyectos asociados a un empleado",
    "status": true
}
```

> no obstante, quiero que se muestren en este orden los nombres, es decir, primero "id", >"nombre", "fechaIni", etc. Lo estaba intentando con ordereddict pero tengo algunos problemas, o tambien creando otra biblioteca haciendo manualmente, pero aun no logro hacerlo

```
{
    "data": 
    [
        
        {
            "id": 1,
            "nombre": "Proyecto A",
            "fecha_inicio": "2023-07-01",
            "fecha_fin": "2023-08-30",
            "presupuesto": 120000,
            "estado": "Activo"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "nombre": "Proyecto B",
            "fecha_inicio": "2023-07-10",
            "fecha_fin": "2023-09-15",
            "presupuesto": 90000,
            "estado": "Finalizado"
        }
    ],
    "message": "Proyectos asociados a un empleado",
    "status": true
}
```

> agradeceria su apoyo, que me recomienda hacer?

Comment: ¿Hay algún motivo o sentido hacer esto? Los valores del json se acceden por sus índices *asociativos*, no debería importar el orden en que estén.

Comment: Dado que `fetchall` por norma general no retorna las filas como diccionarios ¿Estás generando la estructura de `"data"` a través de tu `CustomJsonEncoder`? Si es así, seria bueno que compartieras el código de esa clase, porque sería la responsable del orden que muestras y el sitio donde corregirlo.

Answer (score 0):

No se como funciona Postman, sin embargo, espero poder ayudar de algún modo.

¿Por que necesitas que el object (equivalente a diccionario en json) tenga las llaves ordenadas? Como te mencionaron en los comentarios, los objects asocian un valor con otro, no importa el orden.

Te recomiendo que edites la pregunta y nos cuentes cual es el objetivo. Tal vez así podamos guiarte a una solución más limpia.

##### Sobre tus intentos

- sort_values es False por default
- OrderedDict garantiza el orden de inserción, es decir, están en el orden en el que fueron insertadas las claves. Esto se volvió casi inutil en la versión 3.7, desde la cual los diccionarios comunes también garantizan el orden de inserción.

#### Soluciones

Si bien no se puede agregar cosas en una posición cualquiera de un diccionario o un OrderedDict, si se puede **insertar los datos ya ordenados previamente**, posibilitando que el orden de inserción sea el mismo que el esperado.

Lo habitual en los modulos de bases de datos no es que se obtenga un diccionario por cada fila. Esto me hace pensar que tenés control sobre lo devuelto por cursor.fetchall() o estás usando una ayuda del modulo. Si tenés control, podrías ordenar las llaves de la manera deseada ANTES de insertarlas.

Si no, podés, por cada fila, crear un nuevo diccionario y "reinsertar" los items en el orden deseado. Te dejo un pequeño código para ello:

```
# CUIDADO, si te olvidas de alguna llave en key_order,
# no las va a insertar en el nuevo diccionario
def sortdict(dct, key_order):
    return {k:dct[k] for k in key_order}

dct = {"c":1, "a":2, "b":3}

print("Normal", dct)
print("Ordenado", sortdict(dct, ["a", "b", "c"]))
```

Que produce:

```
Normal {'c': 1, 'a': 2, 'b': 3}
Ordenado {'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 1}
```

Recuerda que para tener el orden de inserción garantizado, debes tener Python 3.7 o superior o usar OrderedDict.